# Is it possible to import / export a vhd which was taken using Hyper-v or vmware Vcenter converter

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I generated a VHD using Hyper-V with size 14.8GB in windows 2012 R2 standard edition and renamed it as win2012R2std.vhd-0.vhd according to this [document](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/import-image) . But while uploading the VHD file in the container using softlayer console , it throws an error showing the file size is larger than 20 mb. But as per the doc, the VHD file size limit was 100GB.

The same error pops ups when using vmware vcenter converter..

Is there any pre-requisites before importing VHD or anything needs to be done to the  VHD before upload ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing relates to the upload limit via the portal interface. I would suggest using something like Cyberduck for larger files.

OpenStack limits the size of any individual object to 5GB.  OpenStack supports storage of files larger than this limit via segmentation.  Additionally, each of the various clients has in place it's own file size limits, and they are as follows:

iPhone/iOS: 20MB for upload/download on the carrier network; 5GB if you're on WiFi though
SoftLayer Portal: 20MB for upload/download
Android: 20MB for upload/download for the carrier network; 5GB if you're on WiFi though
AT&T: 20MB for upload/download
API: 5GB

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/articles/connect-object-storage-cyberduck

Cyberduck can chunk the file and then reconstitute it when the upload completes.

Comment: Thank you . The restriction was because , through console browser , its limited to 20mb. But I got the python script which segments and uploads using API ( I did around 22 GB using this) . Though I have stuck again in lauching the uploaded VHD .. They should have atleast have a tutorials in such things like VHD or other custom imports .